MacBook Pro display doesn't turn off when the session is locked
I'm having this problem from time to time.  When I lock my MacBook Pro, the display should power off after a few seconds.  However, it gets "stuck" with the display powered on... which can mess with my battery life if I do not remember to shut the lid when walking away.
I have sleep disabled, so the system stays on all of the time.  But that doesn't normally interfere with the display powering off when the system is locked.
I can fix this with a reboot, but I'd like to figure out a way to do it without having to reboot.  There's got to be a way that I can either tell what application or background process is preventing the display from powering off... or if there is no such process, then a background service that I can kill/restart to jolt it back into working properly?
